# Qual código deve ser usado pra tirar o foco de um TextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Qual código deve ser usado pra tirar o foco de um TextBox?

Estou criando um sistema, onde preciso que, quando o cliente teclar ESC, o foco do textBox seja perdido.

Como faço?

Comment: seria isso q vc quer: `textbox.Focused = false;` ?

Comment: não, a propriedade `Focused` é somente leitura, não posso alterá-la

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É possível fazer desta duas maneiras:

1. Alterar o foco para um *label*, por exemplo, já que isso não fica 
   perceptível pro usuário.
   Ao meu ver, esta é a melhor ideia porque possibilita escolher o próximo controle que receberá foco ao clicar <kbd>**Tab**</kbd>    .

2. Também é possível alterar o controle ativo do *form* para `null`.

   ```
   this.ActiveControl = null;
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Você precisa de algum outro `focusable control` para pode mudar o focus, você pode setar para um `label`, por example:

```
private void key_pressed(object sender, KeyPressed e)  
{ 
  this.ActiveControl = label1;       
}
```

ou para um NULL

```
private void key_pressed(object sender, KeyPressed e)  
{ 
  this.ActiveControl = NULL;       
}
```